# Delays in displaying search results using Ng-select

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-ngselect

I'm using the Ng-select component with a custom ajax search function on keyup event.

Here's my code :

```
<ng-select [items]="employes"
    bindLabel="displayName"
    [addTag]="false"
    [multiple]="true"
    [hideSelected]="true"
    labelForId="employesmultiselect"
    (keyup)="multiselectSearch($event)"
    [(ngModel)]="selectedEmploye"
    formControlName="multiselect" name="multiselect" id="multiselect" >
</ng-select>
```

And here's the search function :

```
multiselectSearch(event: any) {
    const   employesmultiselect= ((document.getElementById("employesmultiselect") as HTMLInputElement).value);
    console.log(employesmultiselect);
    if (event.keyCode !== 40 && event.keyCode !== 38) {
        if (employesmultiselect.length > 2) {
            this.employeService.getEmployes(employesmultiselect)
            .subscribe(data => {
                this.employes = <IEmploye[]>[];
                this.employes = data;
                console.log(employesmultiselect);
            });
        } else {
            this.employes = <IEmploye[]>[];
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is when i type a text very fast, i don't get the expected results

Example, if i type "user" fast, i get the results for "use", the results for use kind of overwrite the results for "user"

Do you guys know how to fix this issue?

Thanks a lot

Comment: You could try adding a debounce. There is an example here: https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt6#fix-the-herosearchcomponent-class

Comment: Already tried to add a delay, but nothing changed :(

Comment: Consider building a stackblitz example of what you are trying to accomplish so we can better assist you.

Answer (score 0):

This technique has some flaws in it. Each time the user types something an unnecessary service call is made, which is not needed.

I would suggest using `Subject` here, which will update the items.
The difference is, that you can add `debouncetime` and `distinctuntilchanged`, which will reduce service call rate and improve the performance and solve your problem.

Also, please add a loader, so that until a response comes, users should not  see a blank or old response.

You can check the following link about how to add a debouncetime:
[debouncetime and disctinctuntilchanged](https://www.freakyjolly.com/ng-select-typeahead-with-debouncetime-fetch-server-response/)